# Unpublished application Still getting Showing Warning from Google Play

Tags: android, openssl, google-play, google-play-services

I was published my Android application on 31 March 2012 and I was unpublished my Android application from Google Play on 1 Jun 2015. But, 2 days back I got the Warning alert from Playstore for this unpublished application.

> Security alert
>
> We wanted to let you know that your application is statically linking against a version of OpenSSL that has multiple security vulnerabilities for users. Please migrate your app to an updated version of OpenSSL by 7 Jul 2015. Starting on this date, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps and updates that use older, unsupported versions of OpenSSL (see below for details).
>
> REASON FOR WARNING: Violation of the dangerous products provision of the Content Policy and sections 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.
>
> The vulnerabilities were fixed in OpenSSL versions beginning with 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, and 0.9.8za. To confirm your OpenSSL version, you can do a grep via:
>   $ unzip -p YourApp.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"
>
> For more information about the vulnerability, please see this OpenSSL Security Advisory. To confirm that you've upgraded correctly, upload the updated version of the app to the Developer Console and check back after five hours. For other technical questions about managing OpenSSL, please see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mailing.openssl.users.
>
> On 7 Jul 2015, we will not accept app updates containing the vulnerabilities. In addition, we will reject new apps containing the vulnerabilities.
>
> Note: While the issues may not affect every app that uses **OpenSSL versions prior to 1.0.1h, 1.0.0m, or 0.9.8za,** developers should stay up to date on all security patches. Even if you think that specific issues may not be relevant, it's good practice to update any libraries in your app that have known issues. Please take this time to update apps that have out-of-date dependent libraries or other vulnerabilities.
>
> Before publishing applications, please ensure your apps' compliance with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Content Policy. If you feel we have sent this warning in error, visit this Google Play Help Centre article.

**But I don't want to resubmit this app. But I want it in my my developer console applications list.**

**How to Avoid this Security alert. For avoiding this Should, I resubmit the app or should I remove it form applications list?**

Comment: Did you find any solution to this

Comment: Can you share your answer here, I'm also facing this Problem

Answer (score 0):

The message states that "Google Play will block PUBLISHING of any new apps and updates that use older, unsupported versions of OpenSSL." Therefore, when you want to make your app public again, you only have to update your apk with the correct OpenSSL version. Until then, you can keep the project unpublished in your console and you should recieve no further warnings.

I had my update once declined by Google due to a few issues in the app description. The app went unpublished and I was able to fix and republish it very easily. I do not see why this case would differ from that in any way.